Some applications' GUI broken after Windows 11 24H2 update
Ever since the 24H2 update which was installed on my Framework Laptop 13 (AMD) last week, the GUI of certain applications is broken in a particular way. Here are two examples: Synology Drive Client and Advanced Port Scanner:


I tried playing around with the compatibility mode for these apps, but that did not change anything. I was able to "fix" Advanced Port Scanner by changing the display scale from 125% (which I normally use) to 100% or 150%. It does seem like this is related to display scaling overall, though setting the display scale to 100%, 150% or 200% does not fix the Synology Drive Client's GUI. Before the 24H2 update a 125% display scale was not an issue with any of these applications.
I was wondering if other people are experiencing similar problems, at least when using an "odd" display scale (so not 100% or 200%).

It may be totally unrelated to your issue, but the 24H2 update causes issues with color rendering, and broke some games: https://www.techradar.com/computing/windows/gamers-beware-windows-11-24h2-update-could-wreck-your-colors-and-crash-your-games and  https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-halts-windows-11-24h2-update-on-pcs-assassins-creed-star-wars-outlaws/ . Have you tried rolling back?
